# Can I run a VS 2012 project on a VS 2010 Ultimate SP1 installed on Windows 8? How?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I created a VS 2012 project in school and decided to continue it at home, but I have Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate SP1 installed on my laptop and it won't open the project.

My classmates were able to open theirs, and I wonder if the project is just really not compatible or it has something to do with my OS, since my classmates are using Windows 7 and yet they were able to open it without the issues I am facing now.

Comment: What happens when you try to open it?  Do you get any error messages?  What kind of project is it?

Comment: the dialog box says that:
"...cannot be opened because its project type(.contentproj) is not supported by this version of application

To open it, please use a version that supports this type of application."

i also tried up editing the SLN file and it did not work

Comment: You can manually make the VS2012 project a VS2010 project. This of course won't resolve any dependency problems that might exist.  You will spend more time doing that then it takes to simply recreate the project and add the existing files to the proejct.

Answer (score 1):

Open the sln file and change those 2 lines from

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio 2012
```

to

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 11.00
# Visual Studio 2010
```

this only works if the project is a .net 4.0 solution, not .net 4.5 or a plain C++ project.

You can also install the [Visual Studio 2012 express Edition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio_Express#Visual_C.2B.2B_Express). You can download it here:

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-for-windows-desktop#product-express-desktop